# Other Ways of single character to String conversion instead of string() constructor

Tags: c++

```cpp
string exp; // expression
getline(cin, exp);

stack<int> vs;        // value stack (postfix evaluation)
stack<string> infix;  // infix stack (postfix conversion)
stack<string> prefix; // prefix stack (postfix conversion)

for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++)
{
    char ch = exp[i];
    if (isdigit(ch))
    {
        vs.push(ch - '0');
        infix.push(string(1, ch));
        prefix.push(string(1, ch));
    }
}
```

Here I have used `string(1,ch)` inbuilt constructor to convert single character to a String. But I wanna know, is there any other simple way I can convert single character to string in c++?
Like in Java, it can be simply written to convert single character to string is, `ch + ""`

Comment: Use a range base for loop to iterate over the characters in your string : `for(const char c : exp) { if(isdigit(c)) { ... };}`. And please do not use [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice_). `std::cin >> exp;` will also work. And why are you pushing a std::string, I would expect a std::stack<char> and/or a std::list<char> (list can insert items at both ends)

Comment: Is it a sign of a bad coding if I use **using namespace std**? I was advised many times to not write that but I really dont know why...I think that if I use it then I dont have to write **std::** everytime, it's just saves my lot of time and my coding speed also increases. So can you kindly share why...

Comment: No, I took two string stack, one is **stack<string> infix** and **stack<string> prefix**

Comment: Yes I see you use std::stack<std::string>, but I wonder why :)  As for using namespace std :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice. And no typing `std::` doesn't cost a lot of time, certainly not if you get used to it. Fixing one bug caused by a nameclash takes longer. If you want to know more : [stop using using namespace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZqjl9HEPZ8) a video from Jason Turner's C++ weekly

Comment: In general coding speed is the least of your worries , take care writing readabl code first time right. You will probably spent more time maintaining and debugging it anyway.  [Naming things is hard lets do better](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBRoCdtZOYg)

Comment: Well because at the end I need to build infix and prefix expression from postfix expression which is itself a string

Comment: Yeah not first timer but definitely a newbie.

Comment: Ok but can't construct the string when you are popping characters from the stack e.g. use std::ostringstream to append the characters to the string. Or do I miss something there? And I am trying to help, I hope you don't mind giving me this many comments :)

Comment: you want to reduce number of keystrokes? Lets see... `using namespace std;` is 20 characters to type. `std::` is 4, you would need it 5 times. So in terms of typing they are equal, but not typing `std::` makes your code less readable. You trade readability for no real gain.  `using namespace std;` does not so much harm in small code examples, but thats where it helps the least to reduce typing. And you need to consider, code is written once, but read many times. `foo` can be anything, but everybody knows where `std::foo` is from

Comment: code is written once, but read many times. `foo` can be anything, but everbody knows what `std::foo` is. Also you need to consider the time you will spend searching and fixing the most weirdest bugs that `using namespace std;` can cause. In total, it just doesn't pay off

Comment: @PepijnKramer Are you kidding?! I really don't mind at all and I really feel grateful and privileged to talk with Senior Software Engineers as I am lacking mentors who I can look forward to. lol